# Why is the move constructor implicitly deleted when a destructor is defined

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

I am wondering why the committee has decided that a move constructor is implicitly deleted when a destructor is defined.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

struct A { 
  ~A(){}; 
  std::unique_ptr<int> a;
};


int main()
{
    A a;
    A b = std::move(a);
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c0c067fc51260794

Is there any utopic use-case for which this rule "of not default moving the members" makes sense?

Comment: did you mean A a = A(); ?

Comment: [This reference about deleted implicitly move constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor#Deleted_implicitly-declared_move_constructor) might help. And from this, your code should compile fine. So please create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and **Verifiable** Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us, and show us the errors you get from that.

Comment: Actually, your code [compiles just fine](https://godbolt.org/g/2hqxrL). Pehraps you forgot a semicolon after the `struct` definition?

Comment: @einpoklum `-std=c++14` will show the problem. `-std=c++17` avoids it because of guaranteed copy elision.

Comment: I corrected the example! Sorry for misleading

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The thinking is that if you find the need to declare either a destructor or copy special member for your class, then the class must contain resources that need special handling, so implicitly declaring move special members could be dangerous in that the generated code may result in incorrect behavior.

A simple example is

```
struct String
{
    char *s = nullptr;
    size_t size = 0;

    String(char const* s); // makes a copy of the string

    ~String()
    {
        delete[] s;
    }
};
```

If the standard allowed implicit move constructor generation, what would it do? It would simply initialize `s` and `size` in the target object, but it would not assign them to `nullptr` and `0` respectively in the source object. This then leads to double deletion in the source and target object's destructor and undefined behavior.

Implicit generation of the copy assignment operator leads to similar issues as well.

---

Note that C++11 deprecated implicit generation of the copy special members as well for the above example. Unfortunately, they couldn't be defined as deleted because it would break too much code.

[*[class.copy.ctor]/6*](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy#ctor-6)

> If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy constructor, a non-explicit one is declared implicitly. If the class definition declares a move constructor or move assignment operator, the implicitly declared copy constructor is defined as deleted; otherwise, it is defined as defaulted.
>   **The latter case is deprecated if the class has** a user-declared copy assignment operator or **a user-declared destructor.**

Answer (score 10):

The logic is: if you define a destructor that implies it releases resources there, so that compiler-generated constructors and assignments are probably not adequate.